# Mandatory has one relationship.

Tags: newmips

I have to model the following situation: Employees can rise insurance claim which can be for illness or for an accident. Claim for accident requires some additional input (location, police report,...).

I told Mipsy that the `entity claim has a accident`, which was defined later with a `select entity accident`, and the `create filed location mandatory`. So far, so good, the screen *accident* is on a new tab, which I cannot save without a value in *location*.

Is it possible to have a select box `accident/illness/other` on the claim, making the tab `accident` mandatory in case of accident, and accident only?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
select entity claim
add field Type of claim with type enum and values Accident, Illness, Other
```

Then open file "views>e_claim>show_fields.dust" in the editor and add the following condition on tab:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">
            {@__ key="entity.e_claim.label_entity" /}
        </a>
    </li>
    {@eq key=f_type_of_claim value="Accident"}
      <li>
          <a id="r_accident-click" data-toggle="tab" href="#r_accident">
              {@__ key="entity.e_accident.as_r_accident" /}
          </a>
      </li>
    {/eq}
</ul>
```

You can set the same condition in tab content to avoid sending non-relevant data to the browser.